# URLencode numbers?

Tags: php, urlencode

I want to encode this

`广东路20号外滩5号7楼，近中山东一路`
into this:

`%e5%b9%bf%e4%b8%9c%e8%b7%af%32%30%e5%8f%b7%e5%a4%96%e6%bb%a9%35%e5%8f%b7%37%e6%a5%bc%ef%bc%8c%e8%bf%91%e4%b8%ad%e5%b1%b1%e4%b8%9c%e4%b8%80%e8%b7%af`
however [urlencode()](http://my.php.net/urlencode) doesn't seem  to encode numbers and the api I need to use breaks at 20

`--------------------------v

%E5%B9%BF%E4%B8%9C%E8%B7%AF20%E5%8F%B7%E5%A4%96%E6%BB%A95%E5%8F%B77%E6%A5%BC%EF%BC%8C%E8%BF%91%E4%B8%AD%E5%B1%B1%E4%B8%9C%E4%B8%80%E8%B7%AF`

How can I encode alphanumeric characters to the target format?

**From the answer I've created this function**

```
/**
 * urlencodes complete string, including alphanumeric characters
 * @param string $string the string to encode
 */
function urlencode_all($string){
    $chars = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
        $chars[] = '%'.dechex(ord($string[$i]));
    }
    return implode('', $chars);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

urlencode() works this way. It does not need to convert numbers. If you like to convert everything you can do that on your own. Try

```
$s = '广东路20号外滩5号7楼，近中山东一路';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++)
{
  echo '%' . dechex(ord($s[$i]));
}
```

http://codepad.org/bvRU8gQv

Comment: +1. You do not need to urlencode digits and most other ascii characters.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, however like I said, in this case alphanumeric needs to be encoded as I'm conforming to an API that requires this.